# Django TypeError: Field.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Tags: django

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default="")
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __init__(self, name, password, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.password = password
```

**serializer.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'password')

    def __init__(self, name, password, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.password = password
```

**views.py**

```
def find_user(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        id = data['id']
        user = User.objects.get(id=id)
        user_serializer = UserSerializer(id=user.id, name=user.name, password=user.password)
    return HttpResponse(user_serializer.data)
```

Why TypeError: Field.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id' ?

I tried a lot of things ㅠㅠ

Comment: `User.__init__` appears to be missing an `id` parameter

Answer (score 0):

It makes not much sense to override the signature of the serializers. You pass the model object(s) as an instance, so:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'password')

    # no __init__
```

and in the view you thus pass the object with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_GET


@require_GET
def find_user(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    id = data['id']
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=id)
    user_serializer = UserSerializer(user)
    return HttpResponse(user_serializer.data)
```

that being said, passing the password makes not much sense: passwords are (hopefully) hashed, so you can not retrieve the original password.

Overriding the `__init__` on the model is not necessary either, and is even strongly discouraged in the documentation, because it can break all sorts of logic with respect to serializing and deserializing.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to GET requests with the
> [**`@require_GET`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_GET).

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to provide the id, in fact you shouldn't do that manually and let the database decide the id itself, as it does by default ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields))

**model.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default="")
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**serialiazers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'password')
        read_only_fields = ("id",)
```

As for the view, it's heavily flawed.
Your view should probably be a `Response` object from rest_framework.response import Response.

It will help you response to display the proper format.

I can sense this is a beginner project, so I'd recommend you to read the [Django Rest Framework tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) to get a better idea about how everything works